# C++ Passing Dynamically allocated array corrupting heap

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a structure that holds a a handle to a file, as well as data that pertains to the file's identity.

```
typedef struct {
   char* fileName;
   char* filePath;
   char* fileType;
   FileHeader header;
   File* fileHandle; // Allows reading/ from the file

   uint8_t* Read(uint32_t offset, uint32_t length) {
     uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[length];
     size_t bytes_read;
     file->ReadBytes(data, length, offset, &bytes_read); // Reads the bytes at 'offset' in the file into the 'data' array
     return data;
   }
} FileInfo;
```

In various static functions, I use this to read and return data about an arbitrary file. An example goes like this:

```
bool Utility::ReadFileHeader(FileInfo* file) {
    uint8_t* data = file->Read(0x0, 0x10);
    auto header = &file->header;
    header->byte_0 = data[0x0];
    header->byte_1 = data[0x1];
    ...
    header->byte_f = data[0xF];

    delete[] data;
    return true;
}
```

As in the example, I am using the `Read()` function defined in the `FileInfo` struct to read file data. That data is stored in a dynamically allocated array, and when I am finished with the data, it is deleted to free the memory.

However, this appears to be corrupting the heap. Nearly everywhere that this mechanism is used is susceptible to crashing, which always produces `error c0000374`.

Allocating and deleting the arrays inside of the functions that need the data instead of inside of the struct's `Read()` function doesn't seem to produce an issue, but the whole point of implementing it inside of a struct was to make the code neater, as some functions can call `Read()` many times, causing a lot of buffer allocations and deletion.

How can I approach this, where `FileInfo->Read()` can abstract `File->ReadBytes()` from the functions that utilize it while providing safe memory management?

Comment: It's hard to say conclusively from the code you've shown. It could be that `file->ReadBtyes()` is writing to the wrong memory location at some point, but one would need to see more code to be sure.

Comment: You could narrow down many possible memory issues by avoiding pointers in general and  instead pass by reference, use `std::string` instead of `char*`, `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead of `uint8_t*`, and `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` for when you need pointer semantics.

Comment: In C++, there is no need for the `typedef struct`.  Just `struct FileInfo` is all that's necessary.  Second, you asked how to provide safe memory management, but that would be better served changing your `FileInfo` to use `std::string` instead of `char *`, and `std::vector` instead of `uint8_t*`.  The back and forth `new[]` and `delete[]` dance need not be done if you used those techniques.